# ProgressIndicator during a WSTP C function

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, monitoring

My WSTP package includes some C++ calculations which can take a *long* time. I'd therefore like to display a `ProgressIndicator` during this calculation, the progress of which is updated by a C++ loop.

The obvious technique doesn't appear to work:

```cpp
void sendProgress(qreal prog) {

    // send new packet to kernel
    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "EvaluatePacket", 1);

    // show progress bar
    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "ProgressIndicator", 1);
    WSPutReal64(stdlink, prog);

    // a new packet is now expected; caller MUST send something else
    WSEndPacket(stdlink);
    WSNextPacket(stdlink);
    WSNewPacket(stdlink);
}

void myExpensivFunc() {

    for (...)
        sendProgress(...)
        // includes sleeps

    // send actual result
    WSPutInteger(...)

}
```

Though running without error, a `ProgressIndicator` never appears, even if `sendProgress` is called just once.
This is the technique I use to send intermediate `Echo` and `Message` expressions to the kernel before the ultimate function result, so I'm surprised it failed for `ProgressIndicator`.

So I suspect maybe `ProgressIndicator` will need to be invoked in the kernel, possibly with something like

```
wrapperFunc[] := 
  Module[{i=0},
    Monitor[
      myExpensiveFunc[i],
      ProgressIndicator[i]
    ]
  ]
```

but I'm still perplexed how I could update `i` from C++ with intermediate values, say by using `EvaluatePacket`.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Try setting the value of a Mathematica variable periodically from your C code. In an initial test, you can hard-code the name of that variable and _do not_ use `Module` because it will rename it. Then simply hook up the variable to a progress indicator: `ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[progressVar], {min, max}]`. Did this work? If not, please post a complete compilable example of what you tried and I'll take a look. I do not have the time to write an example from scratch.

Comment: My project is [QuESTlink](https://github.com/QTechTheory/QuESTlink), but I'll create a dedicated MWE Github repo. But first; *how* can I set the variable from C, without my C function returning? I can't tell whether WSTP even allows evaluation of an assignment expression, like `a=1`.

Comment: I recommend reading all of the old tutorial: http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf Look at section 1.6 in particular. Any expression can be evaluated, it does not matter if it is `Set` or not.

Comment: The thing is that I would not be able to answer your question without constructing an MWE myself. This is why I asked for one. I don't use MathLink often enough to be able to give a precise answer without trying it out.

Comment: Thanks for the link - it's precisely my solution above :) I hadn't realised `Set` was getting called, but that should do the trick. I'll test this in a MWE and report back

Comment: @Szabolcs It worked! See [this MWE](https://github.com/TysonRayJones/WSTP-demo) (which is just shy of minimum, to demo how I handle errors for someone else). Since my variable is package private, there's little reason to clean it up - but if I really wanted to, I imagine I can pass the local var name (assigned by `Module`) to the C backend. Happy for you to post as an answer, else I'll answer with that repo code

Comment: Please post a self-answer, I'll certainly upvote it. If you can keep the repo online, it will be useful to many people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)'s suggestion, this can be done by using `Set`, to dynamically update a variable used by a `ProgressIndicator` evaluated in Mathematica.
See [here](https://github.com/TysonRayJones/WSTP-demo/tree/master) for a buildable demo.

The relevant code (using the variable names used above, which differ from the demo)...

**MyPackage.m**

```
wrapperFunc[] := Monitor[
    i=0; myExpensiveFunc[]
    ProgressIndicator[i]
]
```

**my_backend.c**

```
void sendProgress(double prog) {

    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "EvaluatePacket", 1);

    // i = prog
    WSPutFunction(stdlink, "Set", 2);
    WSPutSymbol(stdlink, "MyPackage`Private`i");
    WSPutReal64(stdlink, prog);

    WSEndPacket(stdlink);
    WSNextPacket(stdlink);
    WSNewPacket(stdlink);
}


void myExpensivFunc() {

    for (double prog ...)
        sendProgress(prog);

    // send actual result
    WSPutInteger(...)

}
```